# iOS 9 - Distorted UI built with Xcode6 and Swift1.2

Tags: xcode, swift, xib, ios9

My app UI is completely distorted on iOS 9. App is built with xcode6 and Swift1.2. I am using xib's for UI. Minimum iOS sdk is iOS7. everything works well on iOS7 and iOS8. Does anyone know what could be possible issue? I can't post app UI as its for some client.

Comment: Have you tried building with Xcode 7 and seeing if you get any build errors/warnings?

Comment: Yes I get errors because I am using Swift1.2. To run with xcode7 I need to convert Swift1.2 -> Swift2.0

Comment: Not sure how complex and big your app is but you should update to swift 2.0, the Xcode converter does a good job so maybe create a new branch if you're using source control, convert the code and then see if there are any IB warnings.

Comment: problem with converting to Swift2.0 is I am getting so many issues with alamofire :(
And if you know their new library for 2.0 has completely new syntax for completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for you is that you download the Xcode 7 and rebuild your app and deal with the building problem.

**One problem I have met now days is that "Some deprecated API were removed from iOS 9,which make app crashed!"** I think the same is happening at your side also.

You can find all the latest change here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS90APIDiffs/index.html

Build you app with xcode 7 and swift 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for reply but my app is not crashing. Its just UI is distorted completely.

Comment: Deprecated API not only crash the app but also produced some kind on distortion i think.

Comment: I agree but problem with converting to Swift2.0 is I am getting so many issues with alamofire :(

Comment: Yes, there is some changes in request method of Alamofire and also the number of parameters.

Comment: if you know their new library for 2.0 has completely new syntax for completion handler so its not really easy fix to do unless you know any other way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

To Add new Alamofire library to your current project go with the pod installation. below is the code you have to integrate in your pod file for fresh installatoin of Alamofire.

```
 source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
 platform :ios, '8.0'
 use_frameworks!

 pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
```

With the latest release of Alamofire 2.0 request method get change.

I am posting some sample steps which will help you most

Here is my sample code,

```
// Step : 1  
 var manager = Manager.sharedInstance

// Specifying the Headers we need
 manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = [
"Content-Type": "application/graphql",
"Accept": "application/json" //Optional
]

// Step : 3 then call the Alamofire request method.

Alamofire.request(.GET, url2).responseJSON { request, response,  result in
print(result.value)
}
```

Try this or you can check the latest update from alamofire on xcode 7:

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

In previous version of Alamofire there is one more parameter for handle in request method, now that was removed. Check Git for more information. I think this will help you more.

Comment: Hey I know how to use new Alamfire but as this is UI issue and I need a quick fix for it urgently. Thats why I am not converting everything to swift2.0 now.